# AJAX PHP Azure Jquery - I am sure this is a stupid but I can seem to get it to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, azure

I mostly cut and pasted this:

> [Php script to Azure](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)

when I pass a URL to it via a browser, the app runs fine.

but when I try to get the data via an ajax call through jquery (even w/ JSONp enabled) I keep getting an error.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://NOTTHEACTUALADRESS.com&callback=?',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  timeout: 3000,
  success: function(result) {
    alert ("success");
  },
  error: function(result) {
    alert (result.status);
  }
});
```

am I missing something on Azure?

please help!

Comment: Well what is the error?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: sorry should have mentioned error....result.status gives a a 404 (even though the website is up in a browser) and i am running this ajax code inside a cordova/android app and yes the jquery library is included in the app.

Answer (score 0):

got it to work!

(1) activated CORS on azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript

(2) changed in my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

TO

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

OMG I SPENT THE ENTIRE DAY FIGURING THIS OUT!